# Convert time in ist

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get next friday 11 am IST(Indian standard time) based on whatever date is today. I am trying to get the time in unix timestamp. I am not sure how to make the time as 11am IST.
I tried the below code.

```
 //takes dayIndex from sunday(0) to saturday(6)
            dayIndex = 5;
            function nextDate(dayIndex) {
               var today = new Date();
               today.setDate(today.getDate() + (dayIndex - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
               return today;
            }
            console.log("Next Friday 11 am date time in IST in unix is : ");
            console.log((nextDate(dayIndex).setHours(11,0,0,0)).valueOf());
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with native `Date`, but have you tried [`date-fns`](https://date-fns.org/)? I'm pretty sure it should have everything you need.

Comment: Since `ITC` = `UTC+5:30` probably the last line should be: `console.log((nextDate(dayIndex).setUTCHours(11+5, 30, 0, 0)).valueOf());`